# Ranking of National Institutes of Health as Research Institute versus top universities

Tags: ranking, government-institutes

due to lucky (?) circumstances, I ended up as a postdoc at a top 3 university (level of Harvard, Stanford, MIT). However, the supervision and my direct working environment are anything but ideal.

Currently, I am funded by my home government so I could technically switch my job after 12 months. I would have the opportunity for a postdoc at the National Institute of Health in Bethesda and to be involved in a (to me) more meaningful research project.

While the NIH-institutes are well known to researchers in my home country, my current university has a much better standing among the general public in my home country.

Now to the question:

1. Where does the NIH rank as compared to the to top universities for people in the US (both in academia and outside of academia)?
2. Would you consider switching the institution in favour of more meaningful work or is the reputation of the above mentioned institutions in your view way above the NIH?
3. Wich university among all institutions in the US would be in your eyes "equivalent" in terms of reputation to the NIH?

I know, circumstances matter a lot. However, I would be eager to know how a random recruiter at big pharma company would judge two candidates (all other things being equal) from a top university versus the NIH.

Thank you very much for your responses,
J.

Comment: I could only guess at an answer to the questions you ask. But I'll caution, instead, that the unhappy work environment you find at your current place isn't likely to be completely absent at a government funded lab. You will find the good and the bad wherever you may be. Sometimes the pressure alone is enough to bring out the worst. Don't expect utopia.